# perl closured variable returns empty string

Tags: perl, lambda, closures

I cannot explain perl's behavoior in what to seems a simple expression.
I have isolated my problem to this relatively short piece of perl code.
make_peak returns a function that tracks maximum value of a signal v() and keeps this maximum in the closured variable $max.

As it is, the code prints "2". But if I remove kludgy "". in the return statemnt, $p->() returns uundef?

```
use strict;

our $i=0;

sub v($) {
  $i=$i+1;
  return $i;
}

sub make_peak($)
{
  my $vi=$_[0];
  my $max=-1e35;
  return sub() {
    $max=v($vi) if v($vi)>$max;
    return "".$max; # ??? without the kludge returns empty line
  };
}

my $p=make_peak(10);

my $m=$p->();
print $m;
```

Comment: what is your target? this code combines all kinds of variable scope and it's hard to follow

Comment: I am tryng to process signal, which is represented by function v(). I need to calculate several characterstics of this signal. (Example -- max value, as demonstrated). Since I need to have many different characteristics and I want to apply different combinations of them on different signals v(), i tried to do them as lambdas, but hit this strange behavior.

Comment: I don't observe the behavior you report. Both `"".$max` and `$max` will return `2`.

Comment: From your example, the $vi in `v($vi)` is ignored. I presume that is intentional in this example. Second, everytime v() is called $i is incremented, so when `v($vi)>$max` is called $i is incremented to 1, and then it is incremented to 2 in `$max=v($vi)`. Seems like that is not what you want to do.

Comment: To make it look less of a kluge, replace `"".$max` with `"$max"`

Comment: btw, i am using 5.10.1 and when I return `"".$max` I get 2 and when I return `$max` I get 10.

Comment: Does 10 change to 11 when you change 10 in "make_peak(10)" to 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would appear to be a bug in your version of Perl.  Running on

```
This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
```

I get "2" as the output both with and without `"".` on that line.

Comment: This is real sad news for me. I am running "This is perl, v5.8.6 built for MSWin32-x86-perlio"

Comment: Perl 5.8.6 is almost nine years old.

Comment: Yes. And I have to live with it because that is what is installed and it is not up to me to update it.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that you declared the anonymous/lambda subroutine as `sub() {...}`. Just use `sub {...}`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i=0;

sub v {
  $i=$i+1;
  return $i;
}

sub make_peak
{
  my $vi=$_[0];
  my $max=-1e35;
  return sub {
    $max = v($vi) if v($vi) > $max;
    return $max; # ??? without the kludge returns empty line
  };
}

my $p=make_peak(11);
my $m=$p->();
print $m;
```

Comment: That worked, but I do not understand the significance. What about unprototyped sub that makes it more appropriate as a lambda? Isn't it just another kludge?

Comment: when you declared it as `sub()`, the @_ variable from make_peak is passed to the anonymous subroutine. I am unclear how it ended up in $m